# Loading different css files or images based on locale in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, internationalization, resources, globalization

So I have my simple rails application (not data driven), and I have managed (with help from Stackoverflow) to localize it. So I can view the web application in English or German. I have done so using the bundled i18n library. All is good, it was a joy to work with.

Now however, I want to load different images and or css files depending on what locale is active. I want a neat solution to this problem. Not an:

```
if i18n.locale = "en"
  // show this particular image
else
  // show that particular image
```

The above is not neat in my opinion, and imagine how long the if statement or switch statement will get the more locales one adds.

So I was thinking, is there a way I can extend the functionality of the **javascript_include_tag**, the **stylesheet_link_tag** and finally the **image_tag** to allow for locale handling?

I think something like:

```
stylesheet_link_tag "default.css", :locale => true
```

Would be nice to have, where *if true*, the inserted stylesheet will be like:

```
<link href="stylesheets/default.es.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Assuming my new locacle is Spanish. That would be lovely and clean.

Can this be achieved in Ruby on Rails? If yes, I would love some code sample, since I am relatively a n00b to rails.

Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just reference the locale when including an asset. Let's say you want to include a stylesheet specific to the current locale :

```
stylesheet_link_tag "custom_#{I18n.locale}.css"
```

If the current locale is `en`, this will look for the `custom_en.css` file.

A word of warning though : you should make sure to create a file for each locale that you intend to use.

Comment: I can't believe I did not think of that. :) Thanks tigrish.